# Capitalization in Chinese

Tags: writing

Many languages have uppercase and lowercase forms. English for example has lowercase `a` and uppercase `A`. Letters written in uppercase are known as being capitalized. Chinese, also, does have a form of *"capitalization"*.

Numbers for example are considered to have **lowercase** and **uppercase**, uppercase numbers zero to ten including the following common characters:

> 零、壹、贰、叁、肆、伍、陆、柒、捌、玖、拾

What other forms of capitalization, or uppercase, exist in Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides One to Ten and 整(正) you've mentioned, there are also 佰(百), 仟(千), 圆(元).

This [page](http://baike.baidu.com/view/680862.htm) also have some other funny numerical characters, such as 廿 as 20, 卅 as 30, and 皕 as 200.

Answer (score 4):

Those are numerical variant characters used on checks and similar document in order to prevent falsification.

There is no such thing as cased characters in Chinese, although case of course occurs when using Pinyin for transliteration.

You should also realize that ”uppercase” is the original form of Roman characters, whereas the minuscules were later added for easier reading. The term case comes from the literal cases where the printed types were stored: majuscules in the upper, minuscules in the lower.

Comment: The, so-called, *uppercase* numbers are called 大写 in Chinese. Perhaps there are other 大写ed examples....like perhaps: **整（正）**

Comment: Also in Greek the distinction between upper and lower case came in modern times.